# What was Adam’s race?

Tags: history

I’m asking because he it Lucy in Africa or an earlier person found in Ethiopia https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31718336, the evidence shows early humans were Black. Is this found in the Torah?

Comment: Maybe he was heterozygous for everything?

Comment: B"R 36:7 seems to say that certain skin tone developed later.

Answer (score 3):

The race of Adam is not stated in Jewish sources.  There is a reason for that.  A central Jewish teaching is: Why did God start humanity by creating only one man?  So that no one should be able to tell his neighbor, “My ancestors were better than your ancestors”. So that people would know that he who destroys one life is as if he had destroyed an entire world, and he who saves one life is as if he had saved an entire world.  This is found in the Talmud, Sanhedrin 37a-38a.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%AA זהו הנוסח בכתב יד קאופמן[1] ובכתב יד פרמה[2] של המשנה וגם בגרסאות דפוס של התלמוד הירושלמי מצוטטת המשנה בנוסח זה[3], אך בתלמוד הבבלי בכתב-יד יד הרב הרצוג ובכתב-יד קרלסרוהה רוכלין 2[4], וכן בגרסאות הדפוס של התלמוד הבבלי[5] וכן בגרסאות דפוס של המשנה, מופיעה המילה "מישראל", ומתקבל הנוסח "כל המאבד נפש אחת מישראל, מעלים עליו כאילו איבד עולם מלא; וכל המקיים נפש אחת מישראל, מעלים עליו כאילו קיים עולם מלא"